# What's the use of XML file associated with office interop assembly?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, office-interop

When I add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll and compile the C# project, a XML file with the same name is generated in the output folder. It seems that there is no use of this file. I deleted it and the project is still working fine.

I wanted to know why VS generate this XML file and what is it's use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML file you're referring contains documentation for the associated assembly. Visual Studio automatically copies XML documentation files to the output directory if one one is available for the referenced assembly.

To workaround this fact check the following question:

[Preventing referenced assembly PDB and XML files copied to output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011434/preventing-referenced-assembly-pdb-and-xml-files-copied-to-output)