# MSBuild copying PDBs of referenced DLLs

Tags: c#, msbuild, pdb-files

I am using MSBuild command line to build my project and with the help of DebugType=None, the project is no longer producing a PDB file when it compiles - which is what I need as these mess up Clickonce Deployment. However all of the referenced DLLs of the project get copied to the build output folder along with THEIR PDB files.

Is there any way I can prevent MSBuild including referenced library PDBs when copying build output?

Comment: You could add a post-build step to remove any PDBs from the output dir if there isn't a 'proper' solution to this.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011434/preventing-referenced-assembly-pdb-and-xml-files-copied-to-output