# prevent dll's accompany xml file from being copied to output folder in visual studio

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Preventing referenced assembly PDB and XML files copied to output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011434/preventing-referenced-assembly-pdb-and-xml-files-copied-to-output)

for example, I have a c# project which reference `a.dll`, and a when a c# `a.dll` has an accompany xml file `a.xml` for intellisense, when build the project, the `a.dll` and `a.xml` are both copied to output folder, how can i disable copying of `a.xml` to output folder?

Answer (score -3):

If you go to properties of this file in visual studio, you will notice property "Copy to output", which you need to set to "false" in order to prevent its' coping.

Comment: which will also disable the copying of the dll as well

Comment: You can use the following command MsBuild.exe build.file /p:AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions=none