# Don't copy PDBs from installed NuGet packages into /bin/Release

Tags: msbuild, nuget, software-distribution, pdb-files

There are two kinds of references: references to my projects (in my case, they are all in the same solution) and references to assemblies from NuGet packages. PDBs for the first category are useful, and I don't care at all about PDBs for the second category (please, correct me if I'm wrong in my reasoning and I actually *should* care about all PDBs).

Some of the PDBs are really huge (like `AWSSDK.pdb` which weights about 30MB) and I don't want them in my bin folder. I could eliminate all the PDBs using [this msbuild flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8757948/1085375). But I want to keep the good ones (mine) intact.

I could also add a post-build step which will remove all pdbs with name not starting with `MyUniqueProjectPrefix.`, but it feels like a hack.

Is there a clean way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package creator should not have included the `.pdb` in the package, [but should have pushed a Symbol package to Nuget](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package).

The best solution would be to contact the package author to update his package to use this feature.

Comment: I guess, it's the way. As for now, I'll go with `ls $slnDir\packages\ -re -fi *.pdb | rm` after nuget restore.

Comment: It seems like some of the major nuget packages (e.g. MVVM Light) do include PDB files. Is it a mistake?