# How to i create a custom build directory for my WPA app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

I'd like to clean up the generated build of my app so that the app's folder contains a specific folder hierarchy where all of the various automatically included .dll's are placed in a second level folder and not right alongside my .exe

How would i go about doing this in a C# VS2019 solution?

Desired Example structure:

```
[App]
  [Resources]
    Newtonsoft.Json.dll
    System.Data.SQLite.dll
    etc...
  [Data]
    Data.sqlite3
    etc...
  Launcher.exe
  App.config
```

Answer (score 0):

After a day of digging and trial and error, the following solution can be used to generate a clean, custom, styled, hierarchy for the build folder.

1) Add 'probing privatePath=MyFolder' to your project's App.config file.

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="MyFolder" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

2) Add a target node with 'AfterBuild' to your project file. (Open your apps .csproj file in a text editor) Then add one <move> node for each assembly .dll that's just dumped next to your .exe with the source set to the assembly dll you want to move and the destination set to $(OutDir)\MyFolder

```
<Target Name="References" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
  <Move SourceFiles="$(OutDir)\MyAssemblyClutter.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)\MyFolder" />
</Target>
```

**Note:** Build > Clean won't remove your custom folders or their content after this.

For bonus points ([credit to Jason Morse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011434/preventing-referenced-assembly-pdb-and-xml-files-copied-to-output)), to ensure that NuGet packages don't dump their debugging .pdf and documentation .xml files into your release build folder, add the following to your project file within the '<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">' node.

```
<AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
  <!-- Prevent default XML and PDB files copied to output in RELEASE. Only *.allowedextension files will be included-->
  .allowedextension
</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
```